# Proof of The Four Vertex Theorem from Elementary Differential Geometry( A Pressley)

Tags: differential-geometry, curves

In the proof of the four vertex Theorem (A Pressley, Elementary Differential Geometry) we have the following:

Given $k_{s}$, the signed curvature of the unit speed simple closed convex curve  $\gamma$ . We obtain the following $$ \int_{0}^{l} k_{s}'(t) \gamma(s) ds=0$$
First using the continuity of $k_{s}$ we get there exist a  maximum and minimum at $P$ and $Q$ on curve. To claim there are more, we join the points P and Q and divide the curve into two arcs. Then  takes two vectors $a$, unit vector along $PQ$ and $b$ obtained by rotating $a$ along  $\frac{\pi}{2}$ anti clock wise. Then 
$$ \int_{0}^{l} k_{s}'(t) \gamma(s)b ds=0$$

We get  $k_{s}' >0$ on one segment and $k_{s}' < 0$  on the other.

The he claims that it gives  $$ \int_{0}^{l} k_{s}'(t) \gamma(s)b ds> 0$$ in one segment and $$ \int_{0}^{l} k_{s}'(t) \gamma(s)b ds< 0$$ on the other which is a contradiction.

I am not clear how he obtains these inequalities. Even though $k_{s}'>0$ we arrive at inequality if $\gamma(s)b > 0$ or 
$\gamma(s)b < 0$ throughout the segment. How to claim that ?
Or is there any point I missed in the proof ?
I understood the rest of the proof.

Comment: You have a typo (not $k_s$ but $k'_s$ positive on one segment and negative on the other). The point is that you choose $b$ so that $\gamma\cdot b>0$ where $k'_s>0$ and $\gamma\cdot b<0$ where $k'_s<0$, so $k'_s\gamma(s)\cdot b\ge 0$ everywhere, and there's your contradiction. If you can't sort this out, check out the proof in my differential geometry text (free .pdf linked in my profile).

Comment: So the main trick depends on how we choose b. The vector b is obtained by rotating a in such a way that when $k_{s}' > 0$  then $\alpha b $ is also positive. I was searching for a simple material which is also give proper motivation. Your book is good.